# Powerdns setup on ubuntu

Tags: powerdns

I am trying to set up a dns server with powerdns. I am using poweradmin GUI. I have created my custom nameservers with namecheap ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com. At the final step poweradmin asks me for a Hostmaster nameserver. The explanation is: "When creating SOA records and no hostmaster is provided, this value here will be used. Should be in the form "hostmaster.example.net"." Can someone tell me what this is and how am i supposed to do it? I have searched on google but i haven't actually found something to help me.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an email address which can be used to reach the person responsible for the domain. The email address has to be turned into a hostname as explained in RFC 1035:

```
The DNS encodes the <local-part> as a single label, and encodes the
<mail-domain> as a domain name.  The single label from the <local-part>
is prefaced to the domain name from <mail-domain> to form the domain
name corresponding to the mailbox.  Thus the mailbox HOSTMASTER@SRI-
NIC.ARPA is mapped into the domain name HOSTMASTER.SRI-NIC.ARPA.  If the
<local-part> contains dots or other special characters, its
representation in a master file will require the use of backslash
quoting to ensure that the domain name is properly encoded.  For
example, the mailbox Action.domains@ISI.EDU would be represented as
Action\.domains.ISI.EDU.
```

If there are no special characters before the `@` it is sufficient to just replace the `@` with `.`